# My Flask restless create_api is inconsistent

Tags: flask

I am using Flask restless and I am creating an API point

```
manager.create_api(Storeusers, results_per_page=200)
```

But if I try to access the JSON data by the URL endpoint. I get records I have already deleted from the database and it keeps fluctuating. Very inconsistent.

I thought of disabling caching by

```
@app.after_request
def add_header(response): 

    response.headers['X-UA-Compatible'] = 'IE=Edge,chrome=1'

    response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'
    response.headers['Pragma'] = 'no-cache'
    response.headers['Expires'] = '0'

    return response
```

But the resultset keeps fluctuating.
Something like a caching issue or something. Please help.

See the rest api link and see how the data result set keep changing upon refresh

[REST API LINK](https://nameless-caverns-80696.herokuapp.com/api/storeusers?q=%7B%22filters%22:[%7B%22name%22:%22created_by%22,%22op%22:%22eq%22,%22val%22:1%7D]%7D)

Comment: Are you sure those records not on db? Have you test it on db?

Comment: Yes they are not on db, it just keeps showing on and off. I have deleted some and it keeps showing in the result set. It will only stop when I restart the server

Comment: Now Im just regretting using Flask SQLAlchemy. Even converting result set to JSON is something I have not found to work. Always getting Is not JSON serialiazable. I think programming is a bit difficult than to start having issues like this. In PHP, all I need do is json_encode(resultset) Arrrgghhhh

Comment: There is an extension could be useful for json serialize https://flask-marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Okay. I am using Mysqldb.cursor to write the query myself. But I have an issue, in my database I store date in DATETIME but when I get result set JSON. The date should appear as "2017-01-27T16:37:24" but it is appearing as "Tue, 24 Jan 2017 00:00:00 GMT" even when it is stored as DATETIME value 2017-01-27 16:37:24